# Fortran compiler suddenly cannot find "deallocate"

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I am developing a Fortran code and for most of the day have had no problem compiling, linking, and executing.  Suddenly, when I try to compile, in the link phase the compiler tells me it can't find "deallocate_".  Specifically,

```
undefined reference to `deallocate_'
```

How is this even possible?  It finds "allocate" with no problem, by the way.  Any idea what's gone wrong?  Am using Intel 19.0, `mpiifort` on a Red Hat machine.

Comment: As to "How is this possible?", perhaps it's always been missing, but  today you wrote your first code that requires it.

Comment: Without seeing code, we can only guess.  My guess is that you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

As usual without code all is guesswork, but here's one way:

```
Program dealloc

  Implicit None

  Call deallocate

End Program dealloc

  
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran-12 --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 12.2.0
Copyright © 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran-12 -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all -std=f2018 dealloc.f90
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccHOaRlM.o: in function `MAIN__':
dealloc.f90:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `deallocate_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ifort --version
ifort (IFORT) 2021.10.0 20230609
Copyright (C) 1985-2023 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ifort -stand=f18 dealloc.f90
ld: /tmp/ifortro90Qw.o: in function `MAIN__':
dealloc.f90:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `deallocate_'
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ifx --version
ifx (IFX) 2023.2.0 20230721
Copyright (C) 1985-2023 Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.

ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ifx -stand=f18 dealloc.f90
ld: /tmp/ifx0734875725WUp3hq/ifx6BInXp.o: in function `MAIN__':
dealloc.f90:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `deallocate_'
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$
```